# using image inside in gauge insteade of solid color or gradient

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-xe3, gauge

In an old application, I have gauges, two of them actually, now since I don't know how to replace them with loading bars that have animations and stuff I would like to make the gauges have image inside instead of foreground and background color. I saw that they are using `TColor`. Can I replace it with `TImage` somehow? And if yes how? (since i made it to get the color from a directory so I wont have to build every time the same code in Delphi but from an application I made to compile an updater application, the updater application is that that uses the gauges.)

```
procedure LoadProgressParam(list: TListFile; Pr: TGauge; name: string);
begin
  Pr.Top:=StrToInt(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_top'));
  Pr.Left:=StrToInt(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_left'));
  Pr.Width:=StrToInt(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_width'));
  Pr.Height:=StrToInt(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_height'));
  Pr.BackColor:=StringToColor(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_bg'));
  Pr.ForeColor:=StringToColor(list.GetKeyValue('progress',name+'_fg'));
end;
```

Is there something that I can here to change this?

Or I have to make another code to accomplish it?

And sorry if i used the wrong code snipset but i was unable to find how to use the c++ code

Comment: Well you just published a whole unit with (c) by Embacadero. Are you sure you are allowed to do so?

Comment: Gauge? What is this, 1990s VB reminiscence week?

Comment: I removed the Embarcadero copyrighted code that you posted, as it violates both their copyright and their licensing terms. Unless you have their permission to post it in a public location, don't do so. Also, it's not necessary to use **bold** or *italic* for almost every sentence in your post. Spend some time formatting and trying to write more clearly, with fewer run on sentences, some paragraph breaks, and punctuation.

Comment: TImage is intended for static images. It's likely a bad choice for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you replace TGauge with TImage? Yes you can.

Now in order for TImage to work similar as TGauge you need to render its image in two steps. In first step you render the bacground image and in second step you render the foreground image.

Here is a small quick example you can use to finally implement this yourself. In it I use TTrack bar to controll the fill precentage and in its OnChange event I'm caling the CopyRect methods to copy parts of ForeGround and BackGround bitmaps to the final image.

```
procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
var FillRect: TRect;
    ForeGroundBitmap: TBitmap;
    BackGroundBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  //Just a quick code to fill up ForeGround and BackGround image canvases with
  //single color
  //You would prbobably want to load images instead
  BackGroundBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  BackGroundBitmap.Width := Image1.Width;
  BackGroundBitmap.Height := Image1.Height;
  BackGroundBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  BackGroundBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  BackGroundBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(BackGroundBitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);
  ForeGroundBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  ForeGroundBitmap.Width := Image1.Width;
  ForeGroundBitmap.Height := Image1.Height;
  ForeGroundBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  ForeGroundBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  ForeGroundBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(ForeGroundBitmap.Canvas.ClipRect);

  //Background
  FillRect.Left := 0;
  FillRect.Width := Image1.Width;
  //Here we calculate the top of FillRectangle that we will use for bacground rendering
  FillRect.Top := Image1.Height - (Image1.Height * TTrackBar(sender).Position div TTRackBar(sender).Max);
  FillRect.Bottom := 0;
  Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(FillRect,BackGroundBitmap.Canvas,FillRect);

  //Foreground

  FillRect.Top := Image1.Height;
  //Here we calculate the botom of FillRectangle that we will use for foreground rendering
  FillRect.Bottom := Image1.Height - (Image1.Height * TTrackBar(sender).Position div TTRackBar(sender).Max);
  Image1.Canvas.CopyRect(FillRect,ForegroundBitmap.Canvas,FillRect);

  //Since I'm using local Bitmaps here I need to free them to avoid memory leaks
  ForeGroundBitmap.Free;
  BackGroundBitmap.Free;
end;
```

Naturally you would want to make a derivate component from TImage for final results.

Comment: "Naturally you would want to make a derivate component from TImage for final results". Or maybe even TGraphicControl

Comment: thank you very much i am going to test it and post back for the results

Comment: I would not endorse this approach. Use a paint box for bespoke dynamic painting like this. Or a custom control. But absolutely not a TImage.

Comment: All advises were exelent! i tryed all and now i only have to choose which one is more perfect TgraphicControl is very intresting also! Paint box and the code above are the best so far! thank you!!